# Need to color the text for specific stages using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<div class="col item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="course in appplication.course">
  <div>
    <br>  
    <h3>{{course.courseName}} </h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>  
    <h3 align="right" ng-class="Application">{{course.stageName}} </h3>
   </div>    
</div>
```

I have list of stage name. Stage start with three category Application, Interview, Offer using the prefix. I want to show different the stages with colors
ex:Application-Waiting for confirmation.
Try to give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

By using ng-class directive you can add class based on stage of your object, for example

```
<h3 align="right" ng-class="{ 'style-1': course.stageName === 'Application', 'style-2': course.stageName === 'Interview', 'style-3': course.stageName }">{{course.stageName}} </h3>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it another way Thanks for your help

```js
$scope.getClass = function (strValue) {
                        if (strValue.match("Application"))
                            return "Blue";
                        else if (strValue.match("Interview"))
                            return "Red";
                        else if (strValue.match("Offer"))
                            return "Green";                  
                    }
```

```css
 .Red {
            color: Red;
        }
    .Yellow {
          color: Yellow;
       }
    .Blue {
            color: Blue;
        }
    .Green {
            color: Green;
        }
```

```html
 <h3 align="right" ng-class="[getClass(course.stageName)]">{{course.stageName}} </h3>
```

Comment: It can be modified to a directive, so that you can reusable it.